# Xamarin studio 6.3 not starting with window 10

Tags: xamarin.android

**Xamarin studio 6.3** is not starting in Windows 10.

With this I also installed:

1. Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.5.0.486
2. XamarinStudio-6.1.4.1
3. XamarinStudio-6.3.0.863
4. Ms Build tool 2013.
5. Ms Build tool 2015
6. Gtk #2.12.22

When I try to start Xamarin studio, it's not opening.

I also checked the logs. Only the message below is shown:

> INFO [2017-07-14 18:14:00Z]: Starting Xamarin Studio 6.3 (build 863)
>   INFO [2017-07-14 18:14:00Z]: Running on Microsoft .NET 4.0.30319.42000
>   INFO [2017-07-14 18:14:00Z]: Operating System: Windows 10.0.14393.0
>   (64-bit)  INFO [2017-07-14 18:14:00Z]: Found GTK# version 2.12.22

Comment: I also check logs its shows below message only.
INFO [2017-07-14 18:14:00Z]: Starting Xamarin Studio 6.3 (build 863)
INFO [2017-07-14 18:14:00Z]: Running on Microsoft .NET 4.0.30319.42000
INFO [2017-07-14 18:14:00Z]: Operating System: Windows 10.0.14393.0 (64-bit)
INFO [2017-07-14 18:14:00Z]: Found GTK# version 2.12.22

Comment: Since the acquisition of Xamarin by Microsoft, Xamarin Studio on Windows is discontinued. You should use Visual Studio instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this topic on Xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1934/xamarin-studio-wont-start-up), Installing a newer version of [Gtk#](http://www.mono-project.com/download/) solves the problem. (for me, v2.12.45 did it)